# Client side RequiredFieldValidator check for child control of composite control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've created a composite control containing a `DropDownList` and a `HiddenField`. I want to use a `RequiredFieldValidator` to ensure the composite control has a value (it's actually a validator that inherits from a `RequiredFieldValidator`). Currently this works fine server side by adding the following attribute to the top of the composite control's class:

```
[ValidationPropertyAttribute("SelectedValue")]
```

However, I can't figure out a way to do this client side. I've thought of adding this in my RequiredFieldValidator:

```
Control ctrl = this.Parent.FindControl(this.ControlToValidate);
if (ctrl is MyCompositeControl)
{
    // Register script here to do client validation
}
```

...but I haven't found a way to insert the additional validation when the js `Page_ClientValidate` function is called.

How can a child control within the composite control be set as the control to do the client side required validation on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it's actually a validator that inherits from a RequiredFieldValidator` - consider inheriting from `CustomValidator` instead. You'll have to implement the check yourself to see if the mandatory value is present, but that should be no big deal, and what you'll then have is a validator with a [ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which you can set to a javascript function that does what you need.

Comment: That's what I'll do. Thanks! I'll just set the `CustomValidationFunction` as the `evaluationFunction` from a `RequiredFieldValidator` then change that property when the c# code I have above is true.